# Asp.net Programming, output to HTML instead of writing to the console

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I program an Azure Function to read the blob contents from the blobstorage. That works fine, but how can I send this data to my .html template instead of writing the information to the console?

In the attachement I have a picture which explain my problem. I am very new with c# and azure functions.

[image]

Update on 12.07.2020:
I tried another solution, but something wrong in the code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qbZW.png)imgur.com/VX2J7.png

Comment: `using(var reader = new StreamReader(myBlob);` should  `using(var reader = new StreamReader(myBlob))`.......

Comment: Great Seabizkit. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

If 'oldContent' is valid html then you can do something along the lines of this.

```
 public static class MyFunction
 {
    [FunctionName("BlobTrigger")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "")]
        Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(myBlob))
        {
            var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            return new ContentResult
            {
                Content = content,
                ContentType = "text/html"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, but i try to use your code, Visual Studio told there is still a syntax error at the line "reader.ReadToEnd()" and "return" Statement. Could you check please? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the example code, see this guide for more info on using streams - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netcore-3.1